# Windows goes auto-restart after shut down

Tags: windows-8.1, asus-laptop

I have ASUS X550 LD Notebook, on which I have got Windows 8.1 Enterprise installed. The problem is whenever I shut it down, it automatically goes restart.

I tried to search on youtube, and found some references videos. And from those videos, I tried few things:

1. Right Click on My computer -> System Protection -> Advanced -> Start up & Recovery Settings -> Then uncheck the Automatic Restart option.

Sadly this doesn't work. Then I tried another way which I found on YT.

2. Go to search -> and write "Change what the power buttons do" -> and select the search result -> Then click on "Change settings that are currently unavailable" -> Scroll down and uncheck the "Turn on fast start up" and then press save changes.

This doesn't work as well.

Any idea ?

Comment: Anything interesting in the Event Logs?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that ? @DavidPostill

Comment: [What information appears in event logs? (Event Viewer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Thanks for the link. @DavidPostill I can see logs; Is there any way I can export it so that I can show it to you ?

Comment: Right click "System" and "Save all event as". However it would be to big. Look for the last Kernal-Power event. That should be a Shutdown. Are the any errors around that time? What are the next few more recent events?

Comment: Also what is the output from `powercfg /lastwake` (run from a command prompt).

Comment: @DavidPostill Out put of the `powercfg /lastwake` : `Wake History Count - 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was never the Windows which is causing the issue, because I tried installing Linux as well. Same issue was happening with Linux too. So, after all these years, it turns out power button was broken/not working. Replacing it solved the issue.